# Cannot delete homepage web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365

Noticed on SharePoint online that when a site is created without a office 365 groups i.e. `sts#3` template, you cannot delete home page web part and on lists and library’s you cannot save view as.

Has anyone else had this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting?  Being connected to a group or not should not have an impact on this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this alternate way to delete webpart on any page.

Append ?contents=1 to end of url of page.
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mysc/SitePages/Home.aspx?contents=1

It will open below web part page maintenance. Select webpart you wanted to delete(make sure page is checked out first) and click on delete.

[image]

P.S - If you are getting any specific error, please add details in question.